# LuisV3.PredictionOptions doesn't let me timezone - how to do it?

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I figured I'd upgrade my LuisRecognizer to use LuisRecognizerOptionsV3. However I can't seem to set prediction options the way I like - how do I set the timezone?  The v3 prediction options lack this field.

In my bot I am currently doing:

```
var predictionOptions = new LuisPredictionOptions();
predictionOptions.TimezoneOffset = turnContext.Activity.LocalTimestamp.Value.Offset.TotalMinutes;
```

and I can't figure out the equivalent in v3's version of the data structure.

Answer (score 1):

The `timezoneOffset` parameter was mostly provided as a way to determine what day it is for the user in case they say something like "today" or "tomorrow." It also helps when the user enters a relative time like "in three hours." When using the `timezoneOffset` parameter, the returned entity is in the provided timezone rather than universal time.

In LUIS v3, instead of providing an offset you provide a `DateTime` reference and LUIS uses that to process relative time. You can see that documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-migration-api-v3#request-changes). Note that the `datetimeReference` property is only available in [POST requests](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/luis-endpoint-api-v3-0/operations/5cb0a5830f741b27cd03a061) and not GET requests because you provide it in the request body and not as a query parameter.

Also note that the `datetimeReference` property is not currently available in the Bot Builder SDK. You can write your own code to access the LUIS API directly with an `HttpClient`, but if you'd still like a prebuilt SDK to handle things then you can use this NuGet package: [Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.LUIS.Runtime 3.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.LUIS.Runtime/3.0.0)

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
var appId = new Guid("<LUIS APP ID>");
var client = new LUISRuntimeClient(new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials("<SERVICE KEY>"));

client.Endpoint = "https://westus2.api.cognitive.microsoft.com";

var options = new PredictionRequestOptions(activity.LocalTimestamp.Value.DateTime);
var request = new PredictionRequest("Book a flight in three hours", options);
var response = await client.Prediction.GetSlotPredictionAsync(appId, "PRODUCTION", request);

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response.Prediction.Entities, Formatting.Indented));
```

Comment: Will the bot builder SDK add that property?